# How do you reference/import .NET Standard 2.0 types in a .NET Core 2.1 project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a .NET standard 2.0 class library that i keep all my domain classes in (just POCOs no dependencies).

I have a .NET core 2.1 azure functions project also.  In visual studio i added a project reference to the class library, but it doesn't recognize any of my namespaces and classes when I try to reference them.

Comment: can you add more information to your post , and are you sure that you are using .Net Core Azure Fonctions 2.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created an ***azure function***, I see nowhere ***.Net Core 2.1***, currently there are two versions a V1 in ***.Net Framework*** and V2 ***.Net Standard*** as you can see on the screenshot below, otherwise I find this link that you might be interested in, there are people who have the same problem as you, and they recommend to update to ***.Net Core 2.2***.

***The link below:***

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/issues/829

[image]

Comment: so the two things i had to do.. 1. upgrade my azure functions project to use core 2.2, and 2. reference the compiled binary from my .net standard class library. for some reason referencing the project doesn't work